# Term for an enchanted place

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a noun from English folklore.

It should describe a place where unusual, mysterious, possibly magical, occurrences happen.

The locals shun and avoid this place. Its influence might be beneficial sometimes, but it's unpredictable - only the desperate, mad, or naive would seek it.

I suppose archaisms and obscure words should be fine.  I need it for a translation of a fantasy game.

The Polish noun I'm looking to translate is "*uroczysko*" - in case some of the answerers know Polish.

The sites in question aren't one-of-a-kind so unique names starting with capital letters, like Shangri-La or Xanadu, won't do.

Comment: [**uroczysko**](http://www.english-polish-dictionary.com/en/dictionary-polish-english/+uroczysko) *1: nature reserve, 2: **sacred site**, 3: wilderness.*

Comment: My first thought was *sacred land*. I searched a bit and ran into this list which might be useful for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mythological_places.

Comment: It sounds like "surreal".

Comment: FumbleFingers - Does "nature reserve", or "wilderness" fit the description I have provided. "Sacred site" could have all thar, but "sacred" doesn't fit, as site is rather profane. Like 40% sacred, 60% profane. Taboos often have mixed connotations.

@DamkerngT. Thank you, this list might help me research it.

Comment: @tsuma534: I don't know Polish, and I'm far from convinced this question is appropriate for ELU anyway (it's more about translation, writing advice, and matters of culture). I just posted that link for the benefit of others, it being the three definitions from the first result returned by a Google search for **translate Polish uroczysko**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Well, you don't need to know Polish. English is welcome, though. I have provided a thorough description of the term I'm looking for. You might have noticed that this description doesn't really fit neither wilderness, nor a nature reserve.


Yes, I have checked on the meta, and the question is a ELL question. Luckily, I have chosed the correct site.

Comment: @tsuma534: I don't know what you mean by "checked on meta", but you certainly haven't *asked* there if this question is On Topic. As I said, I personally think it probably *isn't*, but for the time being I haven't actually closevoted. In addition to the *translation, writing advice, cultural knowledge* issues mentioned previously, I think it's a racing certainty that any and all suggestions will be Primarily Opinion-based. Which should in principle be Off Topic on ELU as well, but they often tolerate such questions there anyway (and you being a learner is irrelevant to the question).

Comment: I feel like single word requests are on topic, but I'm not sure there's actually going to be a satisfactory answer for this one. I think the best answer is to give it a name and just describe it (ex "The Lost Hiddenlands" can be the proper name, and then just write a few paragraphs description). Because I don't think there's a single English word that gets this across. So the only answer I know to give isn't really an ELL answer. Hmm. Cc @fumble

Comment: @WendiKidd: Regardless of whether there's any possibility of a "satisfactory" answer (I certainly don't think there could be a *single, unambiguously "correct"* one), I just don't see why this type of question should be on ELL rather than ELU. It has no special relevance to *learning* English - it's just another one like the constant stream of SWR questions that turn up on ELU. Sure - they're often *interesting*, but in general I think they're usually about as on-topic as posting a crossword clue. Maybe the "topicality" of this one (here, as opposed to ELU) should be kicked around on meta.

Comment: @Fumble - I'd venture to say that a majority of questions on the Stack Exchange don't have a "single" correct answer. I'd prefer to keep it that way.

Comment: I'm fine with an ambiguous answer. I would be surprised if english didn't had many possible words suitable for the situation.

When I was mentioning the meta, I meant [this question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/14/6500). Top-voted answer states that questions like "My native language has a word for [concept], is there an equivalent word in English" belong here on ELL. And that's an exact description of my question. My native language has a word for a concept which I described, and I'm looking for an equivalent english word.

Comment: I suppose that users on "[Science fiction & Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/)" would be more likely to know the term, but I'm pretty certain I would be criticized for posting on a wrong site.

Comment: @J.R., WendiKidd: I doubt I'm about to be convinced, but if two mods think think the question is okay here I doubt there's much point in me attempting to convert others to my point of view. I guess I'd better just bug out on this one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, if the question isn't really *answerable* I'm not 100% sure it is on topic... In general I think I'm okay with single word requests, but if that's not something the community wants to support then I'd be happy to change my views. So I guess what I was trying to say was "I think this *type* of question is okay, but that this particular one might not be the best fit." Maybe this is something we should create a specific policy for on meta.

Comment: @WendiKidd: Don't get me wrong. It's *possible* that someone will post a word that exactly meets what OP has in mind. I don't know if many/any native Amerindians maintained "sacred/enchanted places", but such things often feature in latter-day movies ("revisionist" Westerns, for example). There could be a word for that (an adopted Amerindian term?!). But what's it got to do with *learners?*

Comment: @snailplane That's an excellent point, and you're right that the meta discussion seems overwhelmingly in support of it. Based on the meta discussion and your and Fumble's support of the migration, I'm going to go ahead and migrate.

Answer (score 4):

**Eldritch**.  It's an adjective, and you can slap it on any geographical feature you want: "an eldritch waste", "an eldritch wild", "an eldritch moor", "an eldritch fen", "an eldritch barrow", etc.

Comment: ... or, using the "wilderness" of the dictionary definition, **an eldritch wilderness**. (Some dictionaries have both spellings, but "eldritch" seems to be more common.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few of names from lore that get reused and repurposed.

One of the first that came to my mind was *Shangri-La*. It seems to fit the first part of what you seek (a place where unusual, mysterious, possibly magical, occurrences happen), although it often refers to a utopian place without the dark aspects you describe (that is, a place that only the desperate, mad, or naive would seek).

The word originated from a 1936 work, but it has been reused so much that [most English dictionaries have an entry for it](http://www.onelook.com/?w=shangri-la). Collins defines it as "a remote or imaginary utopia" and attributes its origin to "the name of an imaginary valley in the Himalayas, from *Lost Horizon* (1933), a novel by James Hilton."

However, some have used the word in ways that could make it seem more mystical and dark. For example, a book entitled *Lost in Shangri-La* is described as "a gripping non-fiction adventure narrative .. an untold true story of war, anthropology, survival, discovery, heroism, and a near-impossible rescue mission."

Another in-the-dictionary locale is *Xanadu*. The word originates from an early 19th-century poem, but some dictionaries indicate that it can be used to mean, "An idealized place of great or idyllic magnificence and beauty." Again, there's not much dark side there, but, for the purposes of a fantasy game, I'd deem it acceptable.

Another interesting term is *Hotel Califiornia*, which hasn't wormed its way into dictionaries yet, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel_California) mentions:

> The lyrics weave a surrealistic tale in which a weary traveler checks into a luxury hotel. The hotel at first appears inviting and tempting, but it turns out to be a nightmarish place where "you can check out anytime you like, but you can never leave". The song is an allegory about hedonism, self-destruction, and greed in the music industry.

All three of these locales show up on a [Wordnik list of metaphorical places](https://wordnik.com/lists/metaphorical-places), and another entry on that list – *bedlam* – seems far less utopian, although it would emphasize the "unpredictability" you seek.

The word *bedlam* now means "a state of noisy confusion," but its [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bedlam) is interesting:

> **bedlam** (n.)
>   "scene of mad confusion," 1660s, from colloquial pronunciation of "Hospital of Saint Mary of Bethlehem" in London, founded 1247 as a priory, mentioned as a hospital 1330 and as a lunatic hospital 1402; converted to a state lunatic asylum on dissolution of the monasteries in 1547. It was spelled *Bedlem* in a will from 1418, and *Betleem* is recorded as a spelling of Bethlehem in Judea from 971.

In short, if there's an exact translation of *uroczysko* in English, I can't put my finger on it, but there are some interesting and exotic words that seem to dance around the edges. And then there's that place Rod Serling made famous:

> “You unlock this door with the key of imagination. Beyond it is another dimension: a dimension of sound, a dimension of sight, a dimension of mind. You’re moving into a land of both shadow and substance, of things and ideas. You’ve just crossed over into… **the Twilight Zone**.”

Comment: Of course, Serling's words are much better when you [hear him say them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzlG28B-R8Y).

Comment: I can't read them *without* hearing him saying them!

Answer (score 0):

I grew up on English-language fantasy literature, and I can't think of a direct translation so general, though there are specific places which have terms which might work for you:

[Fairy ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_ring#Cultural_references)
[Rath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringfort)
[Fairy path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_path)
[Barrow](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/barrow) -- Tolkien used this

Note the wikipedia page on the obscure term [tumulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumulus) is chock full of other terms for interesting man-made geographical features associated with the dead, and reasonably expected to be considered uncanny.

Comment: "Fairy ring" has the meaning I need. But the "fairy" part is unfortunate. It could be disinformating for an english reader, as there there are no fairies in that fantasy world. One could argue that there are no fairies here either, yet we still have fairy rings. So I guess it's a best call for this moment. As for barrows and tumuluses, those are both mounds or other elevated areas - not universal enough. I'll read through that wikipedia entry later, it may contain what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Other possibilities (none exact matches) are Utopia (not all it's cracked up to be), Arcadia, Camelot, Erewhon.

Answer (score 0):

I think **mythical** would be a suitable word as it encompasses both good and bad.

Myths cannot be proofed but are believable.

> historical stories involving supernatural beings or events
>
> widely held but false believed

To seek it, one really has to be mad or beyond logical reasoning (or positively, sense of adventure/zealous curiosity). However, myths can also be enchanting!

> Delightfully attractive and charming.

Since you are finding a word related to a fantasy game, I think mythical explains a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Avalon comes from the Arthurian legends.

It is the timeless, magical place from whence came Excalibur.  Arthur was taken to Avalon after Camlan.

The name is used today for any mystical place, especially in the West Country.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's a single English word which carries the desired meaning. You might like:

- *Faery [or fairy] place [ring, path, mound, tree, etc.]* (noun), though it carries a fairly specific meaning. Particularly in English and Celtic mythology, faery places are magical or enchanted, because of their connection with faery folk, who are notoriously capricious beings. Those who are wary or superstitious (or simply prudent, if these places and their effects are commonly known) will avoid faery places. [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_ring#Oral_tradition_and_folklore), [2](http://www.shee-eire.com/Magic&Mythology/Fairylore/Sidhe/page%201.htm)
- *Fey* (adjective), which comes from the same lore as above. It carries the sense you're after: mysterious, otherworldly, foreboding, and most likely preternatural or magical. This is term I would use. If you want to emphasize the negative atmosphere of the place, I recommend enhancing *fey* adverbially with *darkly*, *uncomfortably*, etc. [1](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fey)
- *Sorcerous* (adjective), though this doesn't imply unpredictability.
- *Unhallowed* (adjective), though this is more sinister than you want.

If you want to add some decidedly dark descriptions, I'd recommend perusing [the works of HP Lovecraft](http://www.dagonbytes.com/thelibrary/lovecraft/index.html), whose writings are packed with sinister and archaic terms. Note though that this is recent (~100 year old) American horror mythology, not English fantasy folklore, though he did make an effort to effect an older sounding style.