# Is there a single word for "visiting someone who is sick"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to use when describing someone visiting someone who is sick?

Comment: _Call upon_ comes to mind even though it is not one word

Comment: I can only find a word in Arab, _`iyaadah_.

Comment: What makes you think there _is_ a word, or that there's _just_ one word? (Maybe you meant, "What's _a_ word to describe..."?)

Comment: @J.R. sadly a lot of people seem to think there's a single specific word for everything, no matter how specific and convoluted. Maybe should ask for a single word to indicate a person who is sick and visits a doctor who is unable to cure him but sends him to another doctor who then goes on to make a wrong diagnosis, causing the person to have to spend years taking wrong medication before finally ending up with a specialist who happens to recognise the rather rare condition she is suffering from because he just read an article about it in the proceeds of a recent congress...

Comment: What do you mean "sadly" Why not ask since there are thousands of such exact words in many languages and English borrows from many of them. In Arab there is a SPECIFIC word meaning just that and a word describing what sort of behaviour it is. In Hebrew there is a similar word for the act of kindness.
In English there is a religious word that specifically means "a clergyman that comes to a sick person": Visitation. It cannot be used here but there is such a word

Comment: @mplungjan 'sadly' because there is a well-recognized problem with single word requests. Yes, there are lots of examples of single words, but there are also quite a few instances where there is no single word for a given concept.

Comment: Why is this considered a problem? If there is none, the answer is "there is none" if there is one or more, the answer can contain those. I see no problem here. If you do not want to answer such questions, don't

Comment: @mplungjan - I think "sadly" here might stem from the fact that so many of these questions could be made more interesting if the O.P. spent a little time explaining why they want the word, or think there might be one. E.g., I find questions like [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173161) and [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194456) a delight to ponder and learn from, but when the question simply asks, "Is there a single word meaning such-and-such" with no motive, no background, no rhyme or reason, those questions seem to fall, well, sadly, a little flat.

Comment: @jwenting - If only there were a single word for such persons!

Comment: @mplungjan - the other reason for 'sadly' is that often this single word is such obscure jargon that using it fails to communicate anything to a reader.  If the word was common, presumably the poster would already know it and not have written the question in the first place.

Comment: I still have ZERO problems with any of your griviances. I learned a new word today in Arab and could not find a good word in English although I was sure there was one, obscure or not. Something like what women did in the 18th century with their friends that had just given birth.

Comment: @mplungjan - Just to be clear, I don't have any "grievances." I made an initial comment because of how the question was [originally worded](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/207922/1); my follow-on was just surmising what jwenting might have meant by "sadly." Perhaps the question could have been improved a little, but it wouldn't be reasonable to expect a first-time contributor to catch onto things that fast.

Comment: philanthropic comes to mind...

Comment: Is there a single word for 'a nurse dropped by parachute'? Yes: 'para-nurse'.

Answer (score 2):

The verb '[to visit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/visit)' carries this connotation and is the term used referring to sick people: (from TFD and dictionary.reference.com)

To visit:

> - to go to see in order to aid or console: visit the sick and dying.
> - to come to in order to [comfort](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/visit) or aid:
>     to visit the sick.

Comment: Actually 'visit', while a fine word, says nothing about the need for a noun meaning a person conducting the visit to a sick person.

Comment: Agreed. Absent some specific additional context (like "I am going to visit <x> in the hospital"), "visit" alone does not automatically convey any "sick" connotation.

Comment: Actually the dictionaries mentioned as well as others give the specific meaning of visit with the connotation described above. I think it is because 'visit' is the most proper  verb you'd use in such a context!!

Comment: It's interesting how some dictionaries list that specific meaning (like [Am Her Def #1b](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=visit)) while others (like [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/visit)) don't. Even if that meaning is not universally listed, though, I still think the smattering of meanings that can be found make _visit_ is a viable candidate, even if it doesn't always convey visiting a sick person – especially with a lack of other suggestions.

Comment: I think Josh, as I, got confused with Visitation, which has one meaning of a clergyman visiting a sick person (for last rites for example)

Comment: @mplungjan - no, I just highlighted the fact that a number of dictionaries suggest that a meaning of 'visit' has that specific connotation. But I agree that you need the  proper context to refer to the sick.